# Can one force svn diff to show svn cp'd files?

Tags: svn, diff

Here is a command sequence showing distinct svn diff behaviours for adding versus copying files:

```
$ ls -A
foo  .svn
$ svn cp foo foo.svn-cp
A         foo.svn-cp
$ svn diff foo.svn-cp
<nothing>
$ cp foo foo.cp-add
$ svn add foo.cp-add
A         foo.cp-add
$ svn diff foo.cp-add
<contents>
```

Some notes to head off irrelevant answers:

- I understand the difference between these two svn actions
- I know that if I were to edit the copied foo.svn-cp pre-commit, the
  diff of that edit would show (vs the
  original foo)
- I agree with the distinct svn diff behaviours

I am only wondering if I can override some default to force svn diff to output foo.svn-cp in the same manner it outputs foo.cp-add.

Comment: What do you need to see exactly? Or why, maybe there is another way, here those two commands work as they should, like you said. I'm not sure I see the purpose of this question to be honest.

Comment: Your "work as they should" is still an arbitrary choice -- for the baseline, svn diff chooses the origin point of the copied file instead of choosing the absence of the file (at its new location).  A case could be made for either.

Comment: It makes perfect sense if you consider that copying files to branches and tags should not show any difference if there isn't actually a difference to show in the file. Think of what would happen when you merge the files back, it would be inconsistent otherwise. But that doesn't say what you are trying to achieve, please give more background if you need any help...

Comment: I do appreciate your interest, but this is the kind-of discussion I was hoping to avoid.  I think my question is clear: "I am only wondering if I can override some default to force svn diff to output foo.svn-cp in the same manner it outputs foo.cp-add".  That is, in the diff, show all lines of the file as added.  Something akin to --no-diff-deleted.  If the behaviour is hard-coded, that's fine - I will work around it for my needs.

Comment: Well, you started the discussion with _my_ 'work as they should', even though you stated in _your_ post you agreed with the behaviour - which now you don't seem to agree with anymore. Sorry but it's confusing. Anyway. The answer to the question is obviously no because of the reason I gave before (but certainly you had seen that from the existing options already), hence my asking what you had in mind to see if there was another way... So AFAIK, I'm afraid you'll have to find a work around.

Comment: I do agree with the behaviour - my question is about overriding the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Unless you want to hack around with the source code; if you do, you’re a better man than I.